# Application build with CMake using OBS pre-compiled binaries (Windows/Ubuntu)

Tags: obs

I am trying to create an external control application in C/C++ to drive OBS in real-time.

I am finding a lot of information about developing for OBS but I have a hard time to differentiate between developing for OBS (say core) where apparently a number of dependencies on 3rd party lib apply (Qt, ffmpeg, etc.) to build the complete enchilada and a normal application build including an API.

I was wondering if there are pre-compiled binaries (Windows/Ubuntu) and c headers that I can include in my project and build with CMake. Actually an API approach.

However, on all documentation I always find **plugin** development and with scripting its about Python and Lua, which I do not want to use.

Could someone help me in clarifying whether the option of downloading shared libraries for Windows/Linux, the headers and include them in an own application is a possibility and where to find more information.

I have been basing myself on this [text](https://obsproject.com/wiki/Getting-Started-with-OBS-Studio-Development) OBS page. Could it be that the term 'plugin' is also used for the OBS C Client API? Yet, in point 2 on this page they point again to a build process [text](https://obsproject.com/wiki/Building-OBS-Studio) that looks like building the complete OBS source with all SOURCE dependencies on other libraries. That is what I would like to avoid doing.

I suppose that the binaries of those 3rd party libraries on which OBS depends will have to be downloaded in all cases.

Thank You

Comment: Plugins do indeed need the OBS Studio compiled to be built. If you're looking to control OBS from a different app, you may find it easier to simply use the built-in [Websocket API](https://github.com/obsproject/obs-websocket/blob/master/docs/generated/protocol.md) in OBS.

Comment: @ProblemsLoop thanks. That is a solution that is even better and more flexible than what i intended to do in API style.